# Encrypt a password using Salt UTF-16

Tags: salt, utf-16

I need to encrypt a password using salt and it must be UTF 16.

This is what i have at the moment but they told me its UTF-8

```
$key = 'dfs7dsfsdf';
$timestamp = '201705111500';
$concat = $key . $timestamp;
$hash = hash('sha256', $concat);
```

Comment: This is incredible unsafe and should not never be used to hash a password. A salt should be unique for each password and ideally be a random value. If your language is PHP then you should absolutely have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$key = 'dfs7dsfsdf';
$timestamp = '201705111500';
$concat = $key . $timestamp;
$cString = mb_convert_encoding($total, "UTF-16LE");
$hash = hash('sha256', $cString);
```

---

You forgot

```
$cString = mb_convert_encoding($total, "UTF-16LE");
```